# Correlation test by category over a list

Tags: r, list, correlation

(sorry I can't post images because I don't have the reputation)

I have a a list of 21 dataframes that I was hoping to perform a correlation test over by categorical group. The categories are under the variable `Station` and are the same for the 21 dataframes.

Please see small snippet of a single data frame below

[This is a small snippet of a single dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La4j8.png)

Below is the code to conduct the correlation test for a single dataframe, with the output below that

```
func <- function(b21)
{
  return(data.frame(COR = cor(b21$Origin, b21$Rainfall)))
}
a <- ddply(b21, .(Station), func)
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3tjw.png)

Am now hoping to do so over the length of the list

```
func <- function(top30clean)
{
  return(data.frame(COR = cor(x$Origin, x$Rainfall)))
}
a <- ddply(top30clean, .(Station), func)
```

I get the following error when I try to run it

```
Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Do I have to lapply?
Cheers legends

Comment: Based on the first function.  may be you need `lapply(top30clean, function(dat) ddply(dat, .(Station), func))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the `list` with `lapply` and a lambda function, use the same code

```
library(plyr)
func <- function(data) {
    return(data.frame(COR = cor(data$Origin, data$Rainfall)))
 }

out <- lapply(top30clean, function(dat) ddply(dat, .(Station), func))
```

-output

```
out[[1]]
   Station         COR
1       b1 -0.22839583
2      b10 -0.34085326
3       b2  0.55192520
4       b3 -0.19323719
5       b4 -0.87735044
6       b5  0.50342343
7       b6 -0.38747112
8       b7  0.13616484
9       b8 -0.30886631
10      b9  0.04089663

out[[3]]
   Station         COR
1       b1 -0.11467295
2      b10  0.38343956
3       b2  0.86669396
4       b3 -0.71142786
5       b4  0.50981405
6       b5 -0.15545226
7       b6 -0.03622854
8       b7 -0.51338336
9       b8  0.16221257
10      b9  0.58353028
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
top30clean <- replicate(5, data.frame(Station = rep(paste0("b", 1:10), each =  5),
    Rainfall = sample(0:100, 50, replace  = TRUE), 
    Origin = sample(75:100, 50, replace = TRUE)), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Oh damn thanks that worked. Can I ask what the function(dat) means? I am very much a novice at this language

Comment: @colinf299 it is just anonymous/lambda function created on the fly